# CRM Dynamics Search wildCard

Tags: search, dynamics-crm, wildcard

I'm exploring Dynamics CRM 4 and when I search a record
for example, a contact, ex. Abcd, Dynamics is searching by Abcd*, 
including, by default, the WildCard in the end.

Is there any way to also include the Wild Card, by default, in the beggining?
Ex. `Abcd --> *Abcd*`

Comment: sorry,  I meant '...Is there any way to also include the Wild Card, by default, in the beggining? Ex. Abcd --> *Abcd*'

Comment: Not that I've run across.  You can always manually type in the wildcard (search *Abcd), but thats not quite as convenient or user friendly.

Comment: You can search using wildcards (* or ?). Asterisks means any character any length, question mark means one digit/character/symbol.

Answer (score 5):

You should be able to build a pre-plugin for the RetrieveMultiple event and access the Query property of the Input Parameters collection, which will contain the search string that the user typed in.  Since you are in the pre event, you can prepend an asterisk to the search string, which should produce your desired results.

Comment: This is exactly how I would do it, I'd toyed with also adding in custom tags like [name] so i can search on specific fields on an entity.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, there is no way to do that. CRM is translating the Search query in a SQL Like at runtime, so, there is even no hack (like modifying a stored procedure).

I've done a custom search by integrating an IFrame in a custom ASPX page to avoid using the default "search engine"... maybe this is an alternate solution to your problem.